# Передача данный между страницами wpf

Tags: wpf, treeview, page

Здравствуйте! Есть страничное приложение, в каком навигация прописана с помощью TreeView. При этом 2 frame привязаны к одной и той же странице. Если пользователь вводит данные на страницу в одном frame, другая страница остается незаполненной. Как реализовать передачу данных между фреймами так, чтобы они параллельно заполнялись? Привожу фрагмент разметки.

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Статистика" IsExpanded="True" Cursor="Hand" FontSize="16">
            <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                <Frame x:Name="frame19" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page14.xaml" />
            </TreeViewItem.Tag>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Анализ" Cursor="Hand" FontSize="16" >
                <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                    <Frame x:Name="frame15" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page14.xaml" />
                </TreeViewItem.Tag>
```

Comment: добавьте скриншоты и лучше напишите MCVE

Comment: ну сделайте в первом фрейме какой-нибудь public метод и из второго его вызывайте