# Навигация в страничном приложении WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, page

Здравствуйте! У меня есть страничное приложение WPF, навигация в котором организована в виде бокового меню, основанного на TreeView. В каждом TreeViewItem.Tag содержится Frame, привязанный к странице. Привожу фрагмент разметки:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvSections"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Background="LightSteelBlue" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >

        <TreeViewItem Header="Главная форма" IsSelected="True" IsExpanded="True" Cursor="Hand" FontSize="16">
            <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                <Frame Name="frame16" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page_void.xaml" />
            </TreeViewItem.Tag>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Клиенты" IsExpanded="True"   Cursor="Hand" FontSize="16" > // тут проблема
                <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                    <Frame Name="frame17" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page2.xaml" />
                </TreeViewItem.Tag>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Данные" Cursor="Hand">
                    <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                        <Frame Name="frame2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page2.xaml" />
                    </TreeViewItem.Tag>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Записи" Cursor="Hand">
                    <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                        <Frame Name="frame7" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page7.xaml" />
                    </TreeViewItem.Tag>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Договора" IsExpanded="True" Cursor="Hand" FontSize="16" >
                <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                    <Frame Name="frame18" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page10.xaml" />// и тут проблема
                </TreeViewItem.Tag>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Абонементы" Cursor="Hand">
                    <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                        <Frame Name="frame10" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page10.xaml" />
                    </TreeViewItem.Tag>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Услуги" Cursor="Hand">
                    <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                        <Frame Name="frame9" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="Page9.xaml" />
                    </TreeViewItem.Tag>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при клике пользователя на узлы дерева (Клиенты, Договора), они разворачивались/сворачивались, но отображаемая страница оставалась прежней. При выборе остальных TreeViewItem страница должна меняться на заданную в привязанном к нему Frame. Сейчас в проблемных местах у меня привязаны страницы, так как без них окно область tvSections становится совершенно пустой. Возможно ли реализовать задуманный план и как это сделать?

Comment: А можно убрать из разметки ненужное? Например, цвета явно не нужны для выяснения сути вопроса.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677794/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Подпишись на обработку событий разворачивания и в обработчике установи `e.Handled = true;`